# Using "news_path" for a :news resource doesn't work with `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/news"} missing required keys: [:id]'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am implementing an admin subdomain and have googled to try and find the answer to this, however I have not found another instance.

My routes look like this for the subdomain section:

```
constraints :subdomain => 'admin' do
  scope :module => "admin" do

    resources :news, :events
    match 'news', :to => 'news#index', :as => 'news'

    root :to => "dashboard#index"
  end
end
```

Events works fine, but for some reason in order for news to work I need to add a specific route to match it. It may help to show the partial where the error is generated (admin/shared/menu):

```
<ul>
    <li><%= link_to 'Home', root_path, :class => "#{current_class?(root_path)}" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'News', news_path, :class => "#{current_class?(news_path)}" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Events', events_path, :class => "#{current_class?(events_path)}" %></li>
    <div class="clearboth"></div>
</ul>
```

And then the error if I was to remove the match route:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/news"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

I just don't have a clue why, any thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found that this is an issue with rails in that the naming convention news should not be used due to plural issues, news -> new so therefore I had to rename everything to articles instead. Oversight on my part, a tad stupid.

Comment: "*news -> new*" is not quite true; have you ever heard someone speak of "an interesting new article" ;-)? The problem is that in the case of "news", it's the same word for *both* the singular *and* plural. You don't need to rename `News` to something else, you just need to use `news_index_path` and not `news_path` (also see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27678933/660921)).

Comment: Thanks for the update, good for others who see this to know they can use it if required. In the end I found it best to avoid using possible plural issues to ensure not only myself but others on the project did not run into any down the road trying to use similar conventions. Funnily enough articles turned out to be a more preferred term by the team and the user base for the project so it was a handy mistake!

Answer (score 6):

The reason Rails gets confused is because "news" is used for both the singular and plural. `news'.singularize` gives `news`; and `news.pluralize` also gives `news` ([Wikipedia has a longer description of this phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plurals#Singulars_as_plural_and_plurals_as_singular); there are [other words that do the same](http://www.vappingo.com/word-blog/101-words-that-are-both-plural-and-singular/)).

Rails will generate a `news_path` route (plural, for the index action) and a `news_path` route (singular, for the show action).
The singular route expects a `News` instance; it appears that the `show` action is defined later, and *overwrites* the index action, resulting in the strange behaviour.

The solution is simple: use the `news_index_path` if you want the index action. I haven't encountered any other issues, and am still using the `News` model.

[ActiveAdmin fixed this issue](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/commit/aafde5187fc2ac3c39a359036e0229c1a6c0519e) in the same way.

If you really don't want to use `News`, then you can suffix it with `Item`, `Entry`, `Object`, or a similar word. This will leave you with a `NewsItem` model with `news_item_path` and `news_items_path`.