# Rails 4 controller News generated by scaffold not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, simple-form-for

I searched about this question, but had no success.

I´m trying to learn ruby on rails, came from php. I generated a webapp with the generation tool, second I generated a News controller with scaffold. The devise and pundit are installed too with gems.

The program works perfectly, the problem is related to the News module, I generated it with scaffold.

The routes where created with the command: resources :news

My idea is to create one _form.html.erb and it be called to create a new record or to updated an existing record. Some tutorials teach to create a new.html.erb and an update.html.erb file and duplicate the code, but I know that is possible to have partials as the main form part.

I´m using simple_form_for and the code to do the new is:

```
# GET /news/new
  def new
    @news = New.new
    authorize New
  end
```

The _form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@news) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :titulo %>
    <%= f.input :resumo %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

When I enter to edit, it works, but to add a new it throws.

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError at /news/new

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"news", :locale=>:en} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Sorry for my bad english, I´m without direction here, is there any way that I can solve it?

Thanks.

====== UPDATED =======

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root to: 'visitors#index'
  devise_for :users

  resources :users
  resources :news

end
```

New.rb (Model)

```
class New < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :set_locale

  def default_url_options(options={})
    { locale: I18n.locale }
  end

  private
  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

end
```

news_controller.rb (Complete)

```
class NewsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  after_action :verify_authorized

  #before_action :set_news, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /news
  # GET /news.json
  def index
    @news = New.all
    authorize New
  end

  # GET /news/1
  # GET /news/1.json
  def show
    @news = New.find(params[:id])
    authorize New
  end

  # GET /news/new
  def new
    @news = New.new
    authorize New
  end

  # GET /news/1/edit
  def edit

    @news = New.find(params[:id])
    authorize New

  end

  # POST /news
  # POST /news.json
  def create
    @news = New.new(news_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @news.save
        format.html { redirect_to @news, notice: 'New was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @news }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @news.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /news/1
  # PATCH/PUT /news/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @news.update(news_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @news, notice: 'New was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @news }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @news.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /news/1
  # DELETE /news/1.json
  def destroy
    @news.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to news_url, notice: 'New was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_news
    @news = New.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def news_params
    params.require(:news).permit(:titulo, :resumo, :texto, :published_at, :user_id)
  end
end
```

Command rake routes

```
news_index GET    /news(.:format)                   news#index
                     POST   /news(.:format)                   news#create
            new_news GET    /news/new(.:format)               news#new
           edit_news GET    /news/:id/edit(.:format)          news#edit
                news GET    /news/:id(.:format)               news#show
                     PATCH  /news/:id(.:format)               news#update
                     PUT    /news/:id(.:format)               news#update
                     DELETE /news/:id(.:format)               news#destroy
```

Thanks in advance.

======= UPDATE 2 ===========

Changing my New action to this:

```
def new
   @news = New.create(params[:id])
end
```

It solved, but everytime I enter, it creates an empty record...

Comment: Please add your `routes.rb` entry for the `News` resource.

Comment: And the code for the News model might be helpful in addition to the routes. Also, are you using I18n for translations? If so, can you post the translation file(s) that you have (either YAML or .rb). The 'missing required keys' sounds like it could be an I18n key lookup error.

Comment: My friends, I updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: When you run: rake routes, Does 'news/new (news#new)' appear before 'news/:id (news#show)'  ?

Comment: Edit works, but the new is not working. I think that simple_form_for is not recongnizing the correct method when it´s a new instance without the id key.

Comment: Do you have any `link_to` on the `new.html.erb` page?

Comment: No, just this: <h1>New News</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

Comment: If I change the content inside the page, removing the form, it will open the page correctly, is something wrong related to the action the form starts.

Comment: The solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5290977/414114

Strange, but Ok!

Answer (score 0):

Use news_index_path for GET /news and POST /news. Rails doesn't figure out the pluralization correctly for the "news" term.
Check the output of `rake routes`, it will be obvious.